# plugin function work only once in ajaxsuccess

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins

hello guys i'm struggling trying to make this work: a popup is generated by a jquery plugin and needs its content to be updated before with an ajax call.
All is working so well at the first call but then the popupMessage function from the plugin appears as undefined...

```
$(".send").click(function(){

        $.ajax({

             url : 'php/ajax/quickMessage.php',
             type : 'POST',
             data : 'photo=' + photo + '&pseudo=' + pseudo,
             dataType : 'html',

             success : function(data){

                $("#message-me").html(data).popupMessage({

                    animation: "flyInUp",
                    delay: 0,
                    showOnce: true,
                    autoClose: false,
                    scrollableModal: false
                });

             },

             error : function(){},

             complete : function(){}

        });

});
```

I even tried with this to check but the problem is all the same:

```
success : function(data) {

    $("#test").html(data);
    $("#message-me").popupMessage({

        animation: "flyInUp",
        delay: 0,
        showOnce: true,
        autoClose: false,
        scrollableModal: false
    });

},
```

Any idea?

Comment: `popupMessage function from the plugin appears as undefined` Is that error message you get in console?

Comment: out of curiosity what happens when `showOnce` is `false`?

Comment: exactly as soon as I call ajax a second time I get the message in browser's console: undefined is not a function - this about my popupMessage function

Comment: Good remark indeed andrew, unfortunately I got the same results with showOnce on false. Actually this plugin has been designed for subscribing a newsletter. This option is to make the popup appear randomly and constantly. I tweaked this plugin a bit in order to stick to my needs. Maybe it is the source of my issue but the fact is it works perfectly when I delete the html(data) method. I'm going to check the plugin code to spot a conflict with it or something of a kind...?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've just fixed my problem - It came from the script located in my ajax file "quickMessage.php". This one does an second ajax call to send an email without closing the popup. Apologize for the misslead. So I thought the conflict was comming from the ajax call itself in this file first then deleted the JQuery library link I had included in it and this solved all my problem - useless to write the code as you all know how it looks like. My mistake was to think I had to re-include the library in my ajax file but I didn't have to.

*Now my 2 ajax calls run properly as much as I want..* kind regards